# Linearizing $x^2/(1-x)$ by partitioning the interval $0<x\le X$

Tags: linearization, nonlinear-programming

We have two decision variables
\begin{align}
& 0<x\le X,\\
& 0<y\le Y,
\end{align}
where both $X$ and $Y$ are two sensible upper bounds on our decision variables.

We also have a constraint

$$y=\frac{x^2}{1-x}.$$

We discretize the interval $(0,X]$ and denote each piece by $r_i$ where $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $n$ is a finite number.

By defining a binary decision variable say $z_i\in\{0,1\}$ where $z_i=1$ if and only if $x\in(r_{i},r_{i+1}]$ and $z_i=0$, otherwise, we linearize this constraint as

$$y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{r_i^2}{1-r_i}\right)z_i.$$

Now the question is how to determine $n$?

I am also aware that there are other techniques of linearization we would like to focus on this method for the moment.

I'm also sure this method has been used before but I could not find any reference on it, mainly because I don't know if it has a name or where to even look!

Could someone help please?

Comment: Why not to set $n$ equal to $X$?

Comment: $n$ is a positive integer number and $X$ is a continuous number.

Comment: This does not address your approach, but in this particular case, since $x^2/(1-x)$ is strictly increasing when $x,y>0$, the constraints can be summarised by $0<x<\min\left\{X,\frac{\sqrt{Y^2+4Y}-Y}2\right\}$.

Comment: As @prubin points out, it must be that $1-x > 0$. So f $y$ does not appear anywhere in your problem other than the constraint $0 < y \le Y$, then $y$ need never be formed, and that constraint can be replaced by the two constraints, $x \le (1-x)Y,-x \le (1-x)Y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume $X\le1$, since the formulation is infeasible for $x > 1$.

What you are doing is a form of *piecewise linear approximation* of the function $f(x) = x^2/(1-x)$. Choosing $n$ is a matter of trial and error. Obviously, the larger $n$ is the more accurate the approximation is. Also obvious is that larger $n$ means longer solution time (and more memory usage).

There are a couple of things worth noting. One is that you might (or might not) get a more accurate approximation using $(r_i + r_{i+1})/2$ rather than $r_i$ as the point in interval $i$ where you evaluate $f(x)$. Another is that it is often a good idea to concentrate evaluation points where the function has greatest curvature. So you would shrink the spacing between points as $x$ progressed from 0 to 1.

**Addendum**: If solution times are fairly brief, one other thing that might be worth trying is to discretize, solve, add break points near the optimal solution (to get a better approximation there) and maybe remove a few breakpoints away from the optimum (to conserve model size), solve again, and repeat until satisfied (or bored).

Comment: Thank you. What does this sentence mean "... concentrate evaluation points where the function has greatest curvature" ?

Comment: Rather than using an evenly spaced grid, put the grid points ($r_i$) closer together where $f(x)$ is changing rapidly (toward $x=1$) and put the grid points points further apart where $f(x)$ is changing slowly (toward $x=0$).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. So let's say $\ell_i$ is the length of the $i$-th interval. Should we set a coefficient $\alpha_i$ and define $\ell_i = \alpha_i \frac{X}{n}$? I'm confused on how to reformulate the constraint above using this idea.

Comment: There is no single correct way to do this. If I had to prescribe an approach, it might be to choose interval lengths so that the increase in $f(x)$ from left to right endpoint is approximately equal on each interval.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried solving the problem directly? This is simply a quadratic non-convex constraint:

$$
y = \frac{x^2}{1-x}\implies y - yx = x^2
$$

So e.g. using Gurobi and Python, you can write:

```
import gurobipy as gp


m = gp.Model()
x = m.addVar(0, x_ub)
y = m.addVar(0, y_ub)
m.addConstr(y - y*x == x*x)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful when I code the problem in python but $y$ appears in other constraints as well as in the objective function.

Comment: How is the fact that $y$ enters the objective or other constraints in any way change the fact that you can model the relation as a quadratic constraint. If the objective and all other constraints are at most quadratic in $x$, $y$ and any other variables, you still have a nonconvex quadratic model.